# Question about the General Binomial Theorem proof provided in the proofwiki

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, proof-writing, binomial-theorem

Recently when I read one paper ["DISSECTING A POLYGON INTO TRIANGLES"](https://oeis.org/A000108/a000108_11.pdf) by Catalan, it uses the General Binomial Theorem in the expansion of $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Then I refer to proofwiki [proof 1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem/General_Binomial_Theorem#Proof_1), and I have question about how **the 2nd equality** got when $f(x)=(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{n!}x^n$ and $D_x f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{n!}n x^{n-1}$:
$$
        \begin{align*}
          (1+x)D_x f(x)&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}
        +\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{(n-1)!}x^{n}\\
        &=\alpha+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}(\alpha-k)}{n!}+\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{(n-1)!})x^{n}
        \end{align*}
        $$
To get the above 2nd equality, it is to prove
$$
        \alpha=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}(1-\frac{(\alpha-n)x}{n})
        $$

But how to proceed then?

Q:

How to get the above 2nd equality $\alpha+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}(\alpha-k)}{n!}+\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{(n-1)!})x^{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}=&\alpha+\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}\\
=&\alpha+\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)}{m!}x^{m}\end{align}$

The first equality is by expanding the LHS and the second equality is by changing $n-1$ to $m$.